# Apache - subdomains, mod_rewrite and virtualdocumentroot

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, subdomain, virtual-directory, wildcard-subdomain

Can anyone suggest how can I achieve the following (I couldn't cook a solution using either mod_rewrite or virtualdocumentroot)::

1) Allow any subdomain on my website, (*.mysite.com should not give 404 error) AND

2) Ensure that the URL that the user sees in the browser is what he typed.

3) No redirects

(Thus, if user types  avalidsubdomain.mywebsite.com, pages should be served from corresponding directory. At this moment I don't care about the directory structure I need to keep. Anything is fine as long as it works. On the other hand, if he types somethingthatdoesnotexist.mywebsite.com,  he should not get a 404, but instead, should be taken to a custom page on the website).

For example, see that any subdomain on blogspot.com will work - like http://dsadsadsdsadsd.blogspot.com/. (Of course Google is Google and heck they can write their own web server). But I am sure something as simple as this can be done in Apache.

Notes:
1) I don't want to add to/alter the apache config or .htaccess every time I add a valid subdomain.

2) From what I have read on various threads, I can use mod_rewrite for a catchall subdomain rule, but then, the URL the user sees in the broser does not remain the same.

thanks!

cheers,

JP

---

I have asked a related question and the answers there seem to solve the problem. 
Mentioning here in case someone sees this question:

[mod_rewrite regex (too many redirects)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069898/mod-rewrite-regex-too-many-redirects/4075369#4075369)

Answer (score 1):

The scenario you want to set up can be implemented with [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html) for Apache httpd.

You just need to create a default virtual host to catch the non-existing subdomains, see [An In-Depth Discussion of Virtual Host Matching](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/details.html) for details.

Example:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /srv/www/custom_page
  # ...
</VirtualHost>

UseCanonicalName Off
VirtualDocumentRoot /srv/www/%1/%2+
```

Comment: I tried this, exactly as you wrote above. But it does not go to custom_page for mistyped subdomains (or any non-existing url) still.  All modules are enabled, apache restarted.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing can be done with DNS, and you'll have to use [wildcards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) to pull it off.

Comment: The DNS with wildcard has already been setup and working fine. Requests to *.mydomain.com are coming to my server. Its just that I want to i) have ability to dynamically add subdomains without reconfiguring apache or anything, and at the same-time redirect mistyped domains to my homepage (or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth:

I have come up [an approach that uses mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11324539/1293558) along with `VirtualDocumentRoot /.../%0` to redirect non-existent sub-domains to corresponding root domains. This does update the client URL but you could use a [P] RewriteRule flag to hide this. It would also be trivial to redirect to a placeholder page as in your example.

Once setup, you do not have to edit any configuration settings to add or remove domains or sub-domains.

Answer (score 0):

in your httpd.conf add

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName default
        ServerAlias *
        VirtualDocumentRoot /htdocs/%-2.0.%-1/%-3
</VirtualHost>
```

Wich wil point your domain at www.example.com to
/htdocs/example.com/www/

Then add a .htaccess file in your rooit folder:
/htdocs/example.com/.htaccess wich includes:
Now every non-existing domain will be redirected to www with a status code of 301 (Permantly Moved). You can change WWW to whatever you want.

```
# Enable Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite all non-existing sites to www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I hope this will help you.