# mod_rewrite regex (too many redirects)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I am using `mod_rewrite`, to convert subdomains into directory urls. (solution [from here](http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=18579)). When I explicity write a rule for one subdomain, it works perfectly:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^[www\.]*sub-domain-name.domain-name.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub-domain-directory/.*
RewriteRule   ^(.*)  /sub-domain-directory/$1  [L]
```

However, if I try to match all subdomains, it results in 500 internal error (log says too many redirects). The code is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^[www\.]*([a-z0-9-]+).domain-name.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/%1/.*
RewriteRule   ^(.*)  /%1/$1  [L]
```

Can anyone suggest what went wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Isn't this a repost of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068775/apache-subdomains-mod-rewrite-and-virtualdocumentroot

Comment: You are redirecting every page to itself, but I don't know a fix.

Comment: @Andrew no it isn't since the OP wants to use `mod_rewrite`. Try putting a static subdomain inside your regex capture group and see if that works.

Comment: @Michael:  I guess you mean something like what I wrote in the question. Static subdomain works. And it is behaving exactly like  Tim Stone and perhaps time Machine are pointing out. I am yet to try Tim's solution.

Comment: Something like that, but try replacing `([a-z0-9]+)` with `(sub-domain-name)` in the second example and see if that works.

Comment: Perhaps you missed (or I am missing something :) - in the first example in my question I use sub-domain-name and it IS working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second RewriteCond will never return false, because you can't use backreferences within your test clauses (they're compiled during parsing, making this impossible since no variable expansion will take place). You're actually testing for paths beginning with the literal text `/%1/`, which isn't what you wanted. Given that you're operating in a per-directory context, the rule set will end up being applied again, resulting in a transformation like the following:

```
path -> sub/path
sub/path -> sub/sub/path
sub/sub/path -> sub/sub/sub/path
...
```

This goes on for about ten iterations before the server gets upset and throws a 500 error. There are a few different ways to fix this, but I'm going to chose one that most closely resembles the approach you were trying to take. I'd also modify that first RewriteCond, since the regular expression is a bit flawed:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}       ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1                !=www
RewriteCond %1#%{REQUEST_URI} !^([^#]+)#/\1/
RewriteRule .* /%1/$0 [L]
```

First, it checks the HTTP_HOST value and captures the subdomain, whatever it might be. Then, assuming you don't want this transformation to take place in the case of www, it makes sure that the capture does not match that. After that, it uses the regular expression's own internal backreferences to see if the REQUEST_URI begins with the subdomain value. If it doesn't, it prepends the subdomain as a directory, like you have now.

The potential problem with this approach is that it won't work correctly if you access a path beginning with the same name as the subdomain the request is sent to, like *sub.example.com/sub/*. An alternative is to check the REDIRECT_STATUS environment variable to see if an internal redirect has already been performed (that is, this prepending step has already occurred):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}           ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1                     !=www
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}  =""
RewriteRule .* /%1/$0 [L]
```

Comment: Hey Tim, Its exactly behaving like you pointed out and it does stop after 10 recursions. I will try to understand your comments and try out the solution too. Thanks!

Comment: This works. Thanks :). These 4 lines can be used to setup multiple sites, multiple subdomains on single server without even VirtualDocumentRoot. mod_rewrite is certainly powerful.

Comment: @JP19: Glad to hear it's working, and no problem; happy to help! :) Yep, mod_rewrite is an exceptionally useful tool.