# Apache Mod_rewrite to change directories

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have been all over trying to figure this out. I apologize if this is a repeat question but I can't seem to find the appropriate solution.

What I'm trying to accomplish is the following:

Given the URL `dev-<sub>.example.com/resources/path/to/resource`, where `sub` varies, go to `/var/www/devEx_<sub>/override/resources/path/to/resource` if it yields a file or `/var/www/devEx_<sub>/main/resources/path/to/resource` otherwise (I can handle the 404s).

I can figure out a solution where I manually add each individual `sub` but I cannot figure out how to do it with a wildcard or backreference.

I've tried messing with `VirtualDocumentRoot` but I can never get the `devEx_<sub>` portion to show up in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` for checking the resource.

I tried using a solution similar to this [ [mod_rewrite regex (too many redirects)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069898/mod-rewrite-regex-too-many-redirects/4075369#4075369) ] but it always messes with the `REQUEST_URI`.

I've tried using something like this in the past:

```
RewriteCond $1 (^resources/.*)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/override%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/override%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]

RewriteCond $1 (^resources/.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/main%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

Also, I would really love to understand using Apache / Mod_rewrite more so, if you have suggestions for a good technical guide or tutorial that would have helped me with this or some debugging techniques (since I have no idea how to debug these rewrite rules), I would greatly appreciate the knowledge so please share!

**EDIT**

Some more details about my trials.

In my `VirtualDocumentRoot` solution, I was able to route to the proper directory but I could not set the directory as the document root in order to execute the override rules.

For this solution [ [mod_rewrite regex (too many redirects)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069898/mod-rewrite-regex-too-many-redirects/4075369#4075369) ], I set the `DocumentRoot` in the conf to be `/var/www` and placed the following lines in an `.htaccess` file in the directory

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev-([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/devEx_%1 -d
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}  =""
RewriteRule .* /devEx_%1/$0 [L]
```

However, this appended `devEx_<sub>` to the `%{REQUEST_URI}`, as you would expect.

Comment: These rules seem to be in the right direction - do they not work?

Comment: Don't you want `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/path1%{REQUEST_URI}` to be `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/override%{REQUEST_URI}`?

Comment: @Jon Edited out the mistake in translation.

Comment: @Ansari These rules work if `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` is `/var/www/devEx_<sub>` and `%{REQUEST_URI}` is `/resources/path/to/resource` but I can't get that configured using `VirtualDocumentRoot` or `Mod_rewrite` in a way that allows me to use the `<sub>` backreference.

Comment: Why don't you make your document root `/var/www/`?

Answer (score 0):

> Why don't you make your document root /var/www/

This is probably the best that you're going to do, depending on what else you serve that isn't in the `devEx` directories, because those will need to be rerouted. You want something that looks like this:

```
RewriteCond $1 (^resources/.*)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev-(.*)\.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/devEx_%1/override%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /devEx_%1/override%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]

RewriteCond $1 (^resources/.*)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev-(.*)\.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /devEx_%1/main%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

Alternatively, you could replace instance of `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` with `/var/www`, though it's kind of ugly, especially if you move your site elsewhere or change your server config. Thus you'd get something like this:

```
RewriteCond $1 (^resources/.*)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev-(.*)\.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond /var/www/devEx_%1/override%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /var/www/devEx_%1/override%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]

RewriteCond $1 (^resources/.*)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev-(.*)\.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /var/www/devEx_%1/main%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

Comment: There's another .htaccess file in the `/var/www/devEx_<sub>` that needs to run to do some additional rewriting. Is there any way to call that .htaccess file as well without messing with the `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable?

Comment: @sgcharlie In the first, when changing document root to `/var/www/` no, the rewrite will always modifiy `%{REQUEST_URI}`, in the second, where `/var/www/` is hardcoded, `%{REQUEST_URI}` isn't changed.

Comment: Right, your examples don't change the `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable. I'm just wondering if there's a way to call `/var/www/devEx_<sub>/.htaccess` in addition to one of these two lists of rules, without appending `devEx_<sub>` to the beginning of the `%{REQUEST_URI}`, if that makes sense.